# making an APK in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.16-dev', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer-0.16_dev-py2.7.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.config.read(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: buildozer.spec, line: 1
'\xef\xbb\xbf[app]\n'
```

i am making an apk in ubuntu and getting this problem..
this error occurs in python file of my program so pls help me..

Comment: What code produces that traceback?

Comment: Looks like the parser is expecting a file, and it is being sent a string, or buffer.

Comment: buildozer android debug deploy

Answer (score 1):

The `\xef\xbb\xbf` sequence is a UTF-8 byte order mark. The `ConfigParser` class does not support reading Unicode entries directly. You need to use `ConfigParser.readfp` with `config.open` to support Unicode within the files.

Since this is in the `buildozer` package when reading `buildozer.spec`, you have little control over that (you could raise a bug report, but that won't solve your immediate problem).

You need to convert the `buildozer.spec` file to ASCII. This will allow `buildozer` to read the file.

Comment: i am not getting any solutions about how to convert it into ASCII format??

Comment: @Kajal If you open the file, then use "Save As" to overwrite the file, you should be able to select the character encoding. The exact method depends on the text editor/IDE you are using.

Comment: i still can't get it...